# WPF I cannot save created TextBlocks

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating app where user can add opinions by dynamically creating TextBlocks. The problem is when I change page, created opinions disapper when I come back to this page. I want to save added opinions after changing pages and exit whole program. I have tried with `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` but that doesn't work.

This is my code used for adding new opinions:

```
private void btnConfirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
            txtName.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            tbName.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            txtOpinion.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            tbOpinion.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            btnConfirm.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            
            var name = tbName.Text;
            var opinion = tbOpinion.Text;

            if (klik >= 5)
            {
                newGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
            }

            if (name != "" && opinion != "" && name != " " && opinion != " ")
            {
                TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                tb.Text = name + ": " + opinion;
                tb.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                tb.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
                tb.FontSize = 30;
                tb.Foreground = Brushes.White;
                tb.Margin = new Thickness(50, 0, 0, 0);
                tb.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
                tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Justify;

                newGrid.Children.Add(tb);
                Grid.SetRow(tb, klik);
                Grid.SetColumnSpan(tb, 3);
                klik++;


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fields cannot by empty!","Error",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Error);
            }

            Properties.Settings.Default.Save(); //That is probably wrong, because it doesn't work
        }
```

Comment: You should be datatemplating from data into ui bound to a collection of viewmodels for this sort of thing.  Think in terms of an itemscontrol with an itemtemplate. Each opinion is an item. Bind an observablecollection to the itemssource of a listbox or plain itemcontrol.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems to tackle with

## Maintaining buttons during runtime

You will need to have some collection, maybe an `IEnumerable` of objects that would represent the data that you can use to create your text blocks. You will also need a method that takes such an object and creates a button for it.

Finally, when your page is being initialized, you need to loop your collection of objects and call the method that creates a button for them.

## Maintain buttons between runtimes

Your application initializes at runtime. You need to load raw data and convert it into a collection of objects and store that into memory, so, whenever you need to load/initialize your page, you will be able to properly reproduce it. This means that you need to store your data somewhere. It could be an initialization file or a database, it's your decision.

However, whenever you create a button, besides adding it to your collection, you need to export your collection into a database or a file.